# TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have some problem in my Django project.

I am new to make web application with django. please help me.

So,

This is my directory path,

```
-lullabyluna
----app_index
------------admin.py
------------index.html
------------__init__.py
------------migtations
------------models.py
------------tests.py
------------views.py
----index.html(I wonder this files path.)
----lullabyluna
------------__init__.py
------------settings.py
------------url.py
------------wsgi.py
----manage.py
----static
```

and my settings.py file include the:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (


    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app_index',
)
```

and this is my url.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('app_index.views',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and finally this is my app_index/views.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

so, I want to know where is the right "index.html" file's path.

Comment: What is the value of `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this in settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH 
)
```

(or)
move your index.html to templates folder & do this,

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + '/templates/',
)
```

Comment: Wow, The first problem is solved, but I had "502 Bad gateway".. is this path problem?

Comment: Well, I think my Django had some error (the error page shows me up the nginx page). My Django version is 1.7.1 so templeate_dirs can be adjustable?

Comment: if is a 502 bad gateway, the problem is not within django. You probably did not correctly configure your nginx + uwsgi (probably). Nginx itself cannot handle py scripts. It need an interpreter - as in a wsgi server.

Comment: But It works well, before I make app_index app. The django welcome page shows up, and when I modify the related files with app_index, it broke up. The "Template_dirs" can apply on Django 1.7.1?

Comment: OK I got it! 
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR),
    )
this is the answer! THANK YOU So much!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Django 1.10.  It worked to use the `TEMPLATES` setting at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/upgrading/  Also, your use of the term `PROJECT_PATH` seems misleading (`name 'PROJECT_PATH' is not defined`), but inserting e.g. `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),` in the DIRS sub-list worked.

Comment: in pythonwhere.com, you need to do this: 'DIRS': ['/home/your_user_name/your_project/templates'],

Answer (score 3):

in pythonwhere.com, you need to do this in settings.py

'DIRS': ['/home/your_user_name/your_project/templates'],

Comment: I tried a lot of solutions but this one helped me. Thanks genius!

Answer (score 3):

Mention your App Name in 'settings.py' in main project folder:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Your_AppName',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You are missing a route to the application index. instead of above, it should be

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('**app_name/**index.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem maybe is at 'app_index/views.py'.
what you do is, create a template folder in the app folder(app_index).
inside the template folder,create another folder called(app_index),then put the index.html file here.
after you do that,in your app_index/views.py,
change this;
" return render_to_response('index.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request)) "

```
      to;

return render_to_response('app_index/index.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

hopefully,it works for you, if all other stuff have no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot to do this with render_to_response, but notice the django doesnt still use render_to_response.
Use **render** instead of **render_to_response**

So,

In the folder {The_name_of_the_Project}, go to edit the **settings.py**

In **TEMPLATES** go to fill **DIRS** with the path of the folder that contains static html file.
If the .html file exists in your {The_name_of_the_Project} folder, then the path looks like: '/home/your_username/The_name_of_the_Project/'.

So DIRS must look like this if the static .html file contained inside {The_name_of_the_Project} folder: **DIRS=['/home/your_username/your_project_name/']**

Answer (score -1):

enter code here lullabyluna ............. put here your template(index.html, home.html, etc) and also put your static folder 
now you get your index and static file after inside index {% load static%}
and end of html {% block content %} and {% endblock %} 
now your page is dyanmic

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean. Maybe using some code formating would help.

Comment: He has become mad by the python monster django